# Hidden reusable blocks in YAML

Tags: yaml, docker-compose

I am trying to define a reusable block in a `docker-compose.yml` file in a way that the reusable block definition itself is NOT included in the final (evaluated) YAML.

I know how to define a reusable block with this syntax:

```
services:
  default: &default
    image: some/image

  dashboard:
    <<: *default
    command: run dashboard
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
```

But, the above also creates an entry named `default` under services, which I would like to avoid. In other words, I need the final YAML result to only include `dashboard` under the `services` property.

Is this possible with YAML? I was unable to find any reference that discusses this structure clearly enough.

Intuitively, I have tried some variations of the below, but it also did not work.

```
services:
  &default:
    image: some/image

  dashboard:
    <<: *default
    command: run dashboard
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
```

Comment: I just wrapped docker-compose with utility `dcw` (docker-compose-wrapper), that generates a new (hidden) YAML file, then calls `docker-compose` on that file. ([ruamel.dcw](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.dcw/0.5.0)). It has a toplevel key `user-data` that doesn't get copied to the hidden file. You need to prevent the merge from *un*expanding in the round-trip by using the SafeLoad `flatten_mapping` on the RoundTripLoad constructor.

Comment: Thats good additional information, but feels like over-wrapping things. After all, docker-compose IS sort of a wrapper...

Comment: When I made this, I needed an easier way to have defaults for missing environments and being able to automatically override information when starting on different servers and from different environments (systemd/updstart). It was easy to do from a template, and it acts just like `docker-compose` with a few extra commands (currently `bash`, `expand`, `generate`, `templates` and `truncate`)

Comment: I hate to suggest this but you could define 1 or more `busybox`-based services with 0 replicas that has your aliases. Then use those references where needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible in YAML 1.2 (or any former version). The reasoning behind this is that YAML has been designed to be a *serialization* language, not a *configuration* language.

The Anchor/Alias construct is nice for serializing cyclic data structures. It was never intended to be used for declaring variables that will be used in multiple places. So currently, the only way to create a reusable structure which can be used in multiple places it to define the structure at the first place where it is used. For example:

```
services:
  dashboard:
    <<: &default
      image: some/image
    command: run dashboard
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
  some_other_service:
    <<: *default
    other_props: ...
```

Also, be aware that the merge key `<<` is not part of the YAML spec and only defined as additional feature for YAML 1.1. It is not defined for YAML 1.2 and will be explicitly deprecated for upcoming YAML 1.3.

We (as in: the people currently working on YAML 1.3) are aware of this missing feature and plan to provide a better solution with YAML 1.3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. At least its good to know that its absolutely not possible. If the merge key is not "official" and going to be deprecated, what is the official way to merge such anchors? All the examples I saw always used this notation, and even Rails comes with this type of configuration for its `database.yml` file.

Comment: As of YAML 1.2, there is no *official* way to do any data transformation operations, because YAML is not a data transformation language. This will change with YAML 1.3 as we adapt to the fact that YAML is predominantly used as configuration language, where one might want to have such transformation abilities.

Comment: @flyx I browsed through all RFCs proposed for YAML 1.3 and still cannot find any support for such feature. Am I missing something?

Comment: @lz96 my initial proposal is [here](https://github.com/yaml/yaml-spec/wiki/RFC-008) and a proof-of-concept implementation is [here](https://ada.yaml.io/trans/). The main result of my experiment was that while adding transformations is possible, it is too complex to really include it in YAML 1.3, because most implementations will probably not implement it.

Answer (score 16):

Docker Compose file format 3.4 adds support for extension fields: top-level keys starting with x- that are ignored by Docker Compose and the Docker engine.

For example:

```
version: '3.4'
x-default: &default
  image: some/image
services:
  dashboard:
    <<: *default
    command: run dashboard
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
```

Source: “Don’t Repeat Yourself with Anchors, Aliases and Extensions in Docker Compose Files” by King Chung Huang https://link.medium.com/N5DFdiC3F0

Comment: Nice contribution to the subject, thanks. Although not a general purpose YAML solution, this can definitely come in handy when using docker-compose. It would be helpful if the answer included a minimal example, as to avoid depending on the external link for more details.