# Using contents of `environment:` for `ports:` in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker-compose

I wanted to make something like this work

```
services:
  api:
    build: .
    environment:
      PORT: 5001
      THREADS: 1
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
```

I guess content of `environment:` is not used in `ports:`. I get

```
WARN[0000] The "PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'ports': No port specified: :<empty>
```

I've searched for an answer, but everything I found was "How to specify an env variable in docker-compose" and "How to use already specified env variable in docker-compose". I want to specify one and use it right away using purely docker-compose.yml.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rely on yaml anchor and aliases in docker compose

`docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    environment:
      PORT: &port 80
    ports:
    - published: *port
      target: *port
```

```bash
# Run
docker compose up -d


# Check
curl localhost
```

###### Related questions

- [Shared variables in docker-compose.yml](https://rosengren.me/blog/shared-variables-in-docker-compose/)
- [Docker Compose merge arrays for YAML aliases and anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178058/docker-compose-merge-arrays-for-yaml-aliases-and-anchors)
- [How to inherit/merge volumes from yaml anchors in docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928519/how-to-inherit-merge-volumes-from-yaml-anchors-in-docker-compose)
- [Explain how `<<: *name` makes a reference to `&name` in docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981096/explain-how-name-makes-a-reference-to-name-in-docker-compose)
- [Hidden reusable blocks in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905033/hidden-reusable-blocks-in-yaml)
- [Anchors, aliases and interpolation in docker-compose.yml environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77565441/anchors-aliases-and-interpolation-in-docker-compose-yml-environment)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do it with - port:port syntax?

Comment: Probably not for now, at least I was able to implement it only using that way.