# Anchors, aliases and interpolation in docker-compose.yml environment

Tags: docker-compose

Maybe I am addressing this in a totally wrong way, but I am trying to follow the first approach (reusing scalars) from [this article](https://rosengren.me/blog/shared-variables-in-docker-compose/#reuse-a-scalar-value-but-rename-the-mapping-the-problem-stated-at-the-beginning).

This is my stripped-down yml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  SqlServer:
    container_name: &sqlserver sql_server
    hostname: *sqlserver
    image: amd64/busybox  
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: &sqlsapassword myrandompassword
      CHECK_POLICY: 'OFF'
    command: /bin/env

  RemoteService:
    container_name: &remoteservice remote_service
    image: amd64/busybox
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Production
      ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS: &remoteport 8081      
      S1: *sqlserver
      S2: *sqlsapassword 
      ConnectionStrings__default: Data Source=$S1,1433;Initial Catalog=easy;User ID=sa;Password=*sqlsapassword
    command: /bin/env
    depends_on:
    - SqlServer
```

I would want to interpolate the anchored variables inside environment values. If I use `env_file` it is loaded but likewise not evaluated in interpolation.

This is the result:

[image: result screenshot]

One can see that S1 and S2 get the anchored value like a charm. But neither `$S1`, nor `*sqlsapassword` are evaluated in the connection string, as if the interpolation would not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML anchors are not a general-purpose substitution mechanism.  They have a specific meaning around attaching the same fragment of the YAML object model to different parent nodes.  If you were using a generic YAML object parser and inspected the specific objects, you should see that the `MYSQL_SA_PASSWORD` and `S2` are literally the same node in the YAML parse tree.  You can't use that functionality to inject scalar-valued nodes into the content of other scalar-valued nodes.

You use YAML anchors in two places, and I'd handle these differently.

For the host name:

```yaml
services:
  SqlServer:
    container_name: &sqlserver sql_server
    hostname: *sqlserver

  RemoteService:
    environment:
      S1: *sqlserver
      ConnectionStrings__default: Data Source=$S1,1433;...
```

Compose can automatically assign container names, and the Compose service names are directly usable as host names within the Compose file.  You don't usually need to set `container_name:` or `hostname:` at all.  Since these names are local to a single Compose file, I wouldn't worry too hard about repeating the names or trying to declare a variable for them.  Just repeat the other Compose service names as host names as needed.

```yaml
services:
  sqlserver: { ... } # without container_name: or hostname:

  remoteservice:
    environment:
      ConnectionStrings__default: Data Source=sqlserver,1433;...
```

The second, trickier case is the password:

```yaml
services:
  SqlServer:
    environment:
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: &sqlsapassword myrandompassword

  RemoteService:
    environment:
      S2: *sqlsapassword 
      ConnectionStrings__default: ...;Password=*sqlsapassword
```

Compose can do limited [environment variable expansion](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/12-interpolation/).  It gets values from the environment of the host `docker-compose` process, or [from a `.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with-an-env-file).  If you create a file named `.env` containing

```bash
DATABASE_PASSWORD=myrandompassword
```

then Compose will automatically load it and make its values available for variable expansion in the Compose file.

```yaml
services:
  SqlServer:
    environment:
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: $DATABASE_PASSWORD

  RemoteService:
    environment:
      ConnectionStrings__default: ...;Password=$DATABASE_PASSWORD
```

I wouldn't generally recommend using YAML anchors.  It's not an obvious syntax if you haven't seen it before, and you quickly get into cases like wanting to combine strings or mappings that the syntax doesn't actually allow.  In a Compose context, many of the examples that I've seen that use them can be simplified (for example, by removing unnecessary `networks:` and `volumes:` blocks) so that there's not significant repeated content.

Comment: Yes, I have figured the _.env_ version also out. Thank you for clarifying.